# How to make an expandable/collapsable section widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, widget, custom-controls, qwidget

I would like to create a custom widget in Qt with the following features:

- It is a container
- It may be populated with any Qt layout
- It may be inside any Qt layout
- A button allows to collapse/fold vertically the content, so only the button is visible, all the contained layout is invisible.
- The previous button allows to expand/unfold it again to the size of the layout content.
- The expanding/collapsing is based on sizes (not on show/hide) to allows animation.
- Usable in QDesigner

To provide an idea, here is an image of a similar widget (not Qt):
[image]

I already have a frame that work correctly and is exposed in QDesigner. I need now to make it to extend/collapse, which does not seem so simple.

I tried to play with resize(), sizePolicy(), sizeHint() but that does not work:
When the frame is collapsed I got following values:

```
sizeHint: (500,20)
size    : (500,20)
closestAcceptableSize: (518,150)
Painted size: (518, 150)
```

QLayout::closestAcceptableSize is not part of the widget so I cannot change it.

**Any hint or/and code snippet to achieve that?**

EDITED:
Here a simple example. I removed all except necessary.

main.cpp example

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include "section.hpp"


using namespace myWidgets;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    // Create the main Window
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(500,500);
    window.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:{background-color:rgba(128,128,128,192);}");

    // Create the main window layout
    QVBoxLayout topLayout(&window);
    QWidget *w1 = new QWidget();
    w1->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(128,128,128,192);");
    topLayout.addWidget(w1);

    Section section(&window);
    topLayout.addWidget(&section);

    QVBoxLayout inLayout(&section);
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton();
    button->setMinimumHeight(100);
    inLayout.addWidget(button);

    QWidget *w2 = new QWidget();
    w2->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(128,128,128,192);");
    topLayout.addWidget(w2);



    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Section.hpp

```
#ifndef SECTION_HPP
#define SECTION_HPP

#include <QPushButton> //for the expand/collapse button
#include <QtDesigner/QDesignerExportWidget>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QDebug>


// Compatibility for noexcept, not supported in vsc++
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define noexcept throw()
#endif

#if defined SECTION_BUILD
    #define SECTION_BUILD_DLL_SPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#elif defined SECTION_EXEC
    #define SECTION_BUILD_DLL_SPEC
#else
    #define SECTION_BUILD_DLL_SPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

namespace myWidgets
{

class SECTION_BUILD_DLL_SPEC Section : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY( bool is_expanded MEMBER isExpanded)

public:
    // Constructor, standard
    explicit Section( QWidget *parent=0 ): QWidget(parent),
        expandButton(this)
    {
        expandButton.resize(20,20);
        expandButton.move(0,0);
        expandButton.connect(&expandButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
                             this, &Section::expandCollapseEvent);

        QMargins m= contentsMargins();
        m.setTop(m.top()+25);
        setContentsMargins(m);
        //setSizePolicy(sizePolicy().horizontalPolicy(), QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    }

    virtual void expand( bool expanding ) noexcept
    {
        resize(sizeHint());
        isExpanded = expanding;
        updateGeometry();

qDebug() << (isExpanded? "expanded":"collapsed") << sizeHint() << QWidget::size() <<
            parentWidget()->layout()->closestAcceptableSize(this, size());
    }

    virtual QSize sizeHint() const noexcept override
    {
        if (isExpanded) return QSize(layout()->contentsRect().width(),
                                     layout()->contentsRect().height());
        else return QSize(layout()->contentsRect().width(), 20);
    }

    // Implement custom appearance
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) noexcept override
    {
        (void) e; //TODO: remove
        QPainter p(this);
        p.setClipRect(e->rect());
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing );
        p.fillRect(e->rect(), QColor(0,0,255,128));
    }

protected:

    // on click of the expandButton, collapse/expand this widget
    virtual void expandCollapseEvent() noexcept
    {
        expand(!isExpanded);
    }


    bool isExpanded = true; //whenever the section is collapsed(false) or expanded(true)
    QPushButton expandButton; //the expanding/collapsing button
};

}


#endif // SECTION_HPP
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem and solved it by implementing the collapsible widget as a `QScrollArea` whose maximum height is animated by a `QPropertyAnimation`.

But since I don't use QDesigner, I can't tell you if it works there.

I still have one problem: Instead of only expanding towards the bottom direction, the collapsible widget can expand towards the top and bottom. This can cause widgets located above it to shrink if they haven't reached their minimum height, yet. But this is really a detail compared to the fact that we have to build this thing ourselves…

**Spoiler.h**

```
#include <QFrame>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QParallelAnimationGroup>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QWidget>

class Spoiler : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QGridLayout mainLayout;
    QToolButton toggleButton;
    QFrame headerLine;
    QParallelAnimationGroup toggleAnimation;
    QScrollArea contentArea;
    int animationDuration{300};
public:
    explicit Spoiler(const QString & title = "", const int animationDuration = 300, QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setContentLayout(QLayout & contentLayout);
};
```

**Spoiler.cpp**

```
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

#include "Spoiler.h"

Spoiler::Spoiler(const QString & title, const int animationDuration, QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), animationDuration(animationDuration) {
    toggleButton.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; }");
    toggleButton.setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon);
    toggleButton.setArrowType(Qt::ArrowType::RightArrow);
    toggleButton.setText(title);
    toggleButton.setCheckable(true);
    toggleButton.setChecked(false);

    headerLine.setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine);
    headerLine.setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
    headerLine.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Maximum);

    contentArea.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { background-color: white; border: none; }");
    contentArea.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    // start out collapsed
    contentArea.setMaximumHeight(0);
    contentArea.setMinimumHeight(0);
    // let the entire widget grow and shrink with its content
    toggleAnimation.addAnimation(new QPropertyAnimation(this, "minimumHeight"));
    toggleAnimation.addAnimation(new QPropertyAnimation(this, "maximumHeight"));
    toggleAnimation.addAnimation(new QPropertyAnimation(&contentArea, "maximumHeight"));
    // don't waste space
    mainLayout.setVerticalSpacing(0);
    mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    int row = 0;
    mainLayout.addWidget(&toggleButton, row, 0, 1, 1, Qt::AlignLeft);
    mainLayout.addWidget(&headerLine, row++, 2, 1, 1);
    mainLayout.addWidget(&contentArea, row, 0, 1, 3);
    setLayout(&mainLayout);
    QObject::connect(&toggleButton, &QToolButton::clicked, [this](const bool checked) {
        toggleButton.setArrowType(checked ? Qt::ArrowType::DownArrow : Qt::ArrowType::RightArrow);
        toggleAnimation.setDirection(checked ? QAbstractAnimation::Forward : QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
        toggleAnimation.start();
    });
}

void Spoiler::setContentLayout(QLayout & contentLayout) {
    delete contentArea.layout();
    contentArea.setLayout(&contentLayout);
    const auto collapsedHeight = sizeHint().height() - contentArea.maximumHeight();
    auto contentHeight = contentLayout.sizeHint().height();
    for (int i = 0; i < toggleAnimation.animationCount() - 1; ++i) {
        QPropertyAnimation * spoilerAnimation = static_cast<QPropertyAnimation *>(toggleAnimation.animationAt(i));
        spoilerAnimation->setDuration(animationDuration);
        spoilerAnimation->setStartValue(collapsedHeight);
        spoilerAnimation->setEndValue(collapsedHeight + contentHeight);
    }
    QPropertyAnimation * contentAnimation = static_cast<QPropertyAnimation *>(toggleAnimation.animationAt(toggleAnimation.animationCount() - 1));
    contentAnimation->setDuration(animationDuration);
    contentAnimation->setStartValue(0);
    contentAnimation->setEndValue(contentHeight);
}
```

**How to use it:**

```
…
auto * anyLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
anyLayout->addWidget(…);
…
Spoiler spoiler;
spoiler.setContentLayout(*anyLayout);
…
```

[image: Spoiler example]

Comment: I would like to fork and modify your solution in some details. Then, I would like to add it at github or somewhere. Do you allow this? How can I reference to you, is just a link to this thread fine?

Comment: Sure, go ahead :)

Comment: Can you give me the link to your repo too?

Comment: @IceFire Using this code, what is the best way to force the parent widget to update its size when the animation is performed?

Comment: @manatttta Which kind of parent widget would you like to update? Usually, expecting the other widget (here, a table) to shrink feels more natural

Comment: @IceFire I am using this at the bottom of a  `QDialog` for some optional widgets to show up. When I expand the `Section` widget, the `QDialog` object expands its size, but when I retract the `Section` widget, the `QDialog`object keeps its size, resulting in empty space. I can update my dialog's size correctly if I call its `QDialog::adjustSize()` inside `Section::resizeEvent()`, but this results in flicker

Comment: Regarding this issue one idea which I didn't find the time to implement yet is to turn the collapsible widget into a floating widget that appears to be docked. That way it would expand and collapse without changing any other widget's size. Of course it will overlap stuff if it's not at the very bottom of the parent.

Comment: @x squared @IceFire The code on github repo need to have the copyright owner information. (name <email>) with a lgpl header. (though the LICENCE file does help somewhat - better place lgpl header with author info). AND Nice work!

Comment: @KuldeepSinghDhaka Thanks, will add it

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this super useful code!!! I have a small problem though, I would like to put QLabel inside the the collapsible section, the text in the QLabel is long and I set QLabel::setWordWrap(true), but the size of the label doesn't adjust leaving empy lines. Using QLabel::adjustSize() has no effect.

Comment: Hm, it works just fine for me. A long label content simply causes the expanded region to be bigger to fit all the text. I think a look at your code is necessary to understand what’s going on. Maybe in a separate question referencing this answer.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust this code for content that changes its size over time? I want to dynamically add/remove content from the collapse-area, but it seems like the size when expanded gets not adjusted automatically...

Comment: I don't have much time atm. But you could extract the relevant part  of `setContentLayout() ` into a separate function and call it whenever the content changes. The relevant part is the one in which the `contentHeight` and `collapsedHeight` are calculated and used.

Comment: For anyone still referring to this answer. I've switched the clicked signal to the toggled signal to allow expand/collapse to be toggled externally to the button. Was useful for me so I could implement expand all / collapse all functionality.

Comment: Does the github repo mentioned in comments still exist? Could anyone provide a link?

Comment: Not sure why the comment vanished, but here is the link to IceFire’s repo:
https://github.com/Elypson/qt-collapsible-section

Comment: just add spacer item to layout under that , It will prevent that problem! (expanding towards  [top-bottom])
It solved my problem too.

Comment: Can you concretize what you mean? I don’t see how a spacer fixes the problem right now.

Comment: I edited that to support pyside6 and setup.py https://github.com/eyalk11/qt-collapsible-section . There is some bug that required me to ignore the border:none.

Answer (score 37):

Even though this is old I found this thread helpful. However, I'm working in python, so I had to convert the C++ code.
Just in case anyone is looking for a python version of x squared's solution. Here is my port:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Spoiler(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title='', animationDuration=300):
        """
        References:
            # Adapted from c++ version
            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476006/how-to-make-an-expandable-collapsable-section-widget-in-qt
        """
        super(Spoiler, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
        self.toggleAnimation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup()
        self.contentArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.headerLine = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.toggleButton = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        toggleButton = self.toggleButton
        toggleButton.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; }")
        toggleButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        toggleButton.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        toggleButton.setText(str(title))
        toggleButton.setCheckable(True)
        toggleButton.setChecked(False)

        headerLine = self.headerLine
        headerLine.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.HLine)
        headerLine.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        headerLine.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        self.contentArea.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { background-color: white; border: none; }")
        self.contentArea.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        # start out collapsed
        self.contentArea.setMaximumHeight(0)
        self.contentArea.setMinimumHeight(0)
        # let the entire widget grow and shrink with its content
        toggleAnimation = self.toggleAnimation
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.contentArea, b"maximumHeight"))
        # don't waste space
        mainLayout = self.mainLayout
        mainLayout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        row = 0
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.toggleButton, row, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.headerLine, row, 2, 1, 1)
        row += 1
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.contentArea, row, 0, 1, 3)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        def start_animation(checked):
            arrow_type = QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
            direction = QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward if checked else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
            toggleButton.setArrowType(arrow_type)
            self.toggleAnimation.setDirection(direction)
            self.toggleAnimation.start()

        self.toggleButton.clicked.connect(start_animation)

    def setContentLayout(self, contentLayout):
        # Not sure if this is equivalent to self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.setLayout(contentLayout)
        collapsedHeight = self.sizeHint().height() - self.contentArea.maximumHeight()
        contentHeight = contentLayout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount()-1):
            spoilerAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(i)
            spoilerAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
            spoilerAnimation.setStartValue(collapsedHeight)
            spoilerAnimation.setEndValue(collapsedHeight + contentHeight)
        contentAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount() - 1)
        contentAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
        contentAnimation.setStartValue(0)
        contentAnimation.setEndValue(contentHeight)
```

Comment: Like I commented above: Switching the clicked signal to the toggled signal allows expand/collapse to be toggled externally to the button. Was useful for me so I could implement expand all / collapse all functionality.

Answer (score 14):

I have dug through the excellent pointer provided by @LoPiTal and converted it to PyQt5 (Python3). I think it's very elegant.

In case anyone is looking for a PyQt-solution, here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QDialog, QTreeWidget,
                             QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout,
                             QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QLabel,
                             QApplication)

class SectionExpandButton(QPushButton):
    """a QPushbutton that can expand or collapse its section
    """
    def __init__(self, item, text = "", parent = None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.section = item
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self):
        """toggle expand/collapse of section by clicking
        """
        if self.section.isExpanded():
            self.section.setExpanded(False)
        else:
            self.section.setExpanded(True)


class CollapsibleDialog(QDialog):
    """a dialog to which collapsible sections can be added;
    subclass and reimplement define_sections() to define sections and
        add them as (title, widget) tuples to self.sections
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tree = QTreeWidget()
        self.tree.setHeaderHidden(True)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.tree.setIndentation(0)

        self.sections = []
        self.define_sections()
        self.add_sections()

    def add_sections(self):
        """adds a collapsible sections for every 
        (title, widget) tuple in self.sections
        """
        for (title, widget) in self.sections:
            button1 = self.add_button(title)
            section1 = self.add_widget(button1, widget)
            button1.addChild(section1)

    def define_sections(self):
        """reimplement this to define all your sections
        and add them as (title, widget) tuples to self.sections
        """
        widget = QFrame(self.tree)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Bla"))
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Blubb"))
        title = "Section 1"
        self.sections.append((title, widget))

    def add_button(self, title):
        """creates a QTreeWidgetItem containing a button 
        to expand or collapse its section
        """
        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
        self.tree.addTopLevelItem(item)
        self.tree.setItemWidget(item, 0, SectionExpandButton(item, text = title))
        return item

    def add_widget(self, button, widget):
        """creates a QWidgetItem containing the widget,
        as child of the button-QWidgetItem
        """
        section = QTreeWidgetItem(button)
        section.setDisabled(True)
        self.tree.setItemWidget(section, 0, widget)
        return section


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = CollapsibleDialog()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This solution is quite complicated and would not really recommend it based on what people requested.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is not a good way to answer a question, just with a link, but I think this blog post is quite relevant:

http://www.fancyaddress.com/blog/qt-2/create-something-like-the-widget-box-as-in-the-qt-designer/

It is based on QTreeWidget, and uses its expand / collapse features, which are already implemented.
It explains how widgets can be added to the tree widget items, and how to add a button to use for collapse / expand them.

Of course, all the credit goes for the post author.

Comment: Very elegant, thanks a lot for the pointer! I have converted it to PyQt5 and added the code as a separate answer. Hope it helps someone else eventually.

Comment: +1. I googled "qt-designer widget-box source" and found [this link](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qttools/src/designer/src/components/widgetbox/widgetbox.cpp.html), which (assuming it's the real source) shows that the Widget Box is in fact implemented as a QTreeView, similar to the example you linked.

Comment: @Boon Yes, following your links, you can find the actual implementation of the tree widget behind the widget-box [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qttools/src/designer/src/components/widgetbox/widgetboxtreewidget.cpp.html). Combine it with a custom [item delegate](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qttools/src/designer/src/lib/shared/sheet_delegate.cpp.html) and you can hide the default tree widget appearance. All in the Qt way :D

Comment: The site is down, here's an archive link to the code: https://web.archive.org/web/20230604043944/https://blog.fancyaddress.com/qt-2/create-something-like-the-widget-box-as-in-the-qt-designer/

And here's a screenshot on internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20190707122905/http://www.fancyaddress.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/25u5yzr.png

Answer (score 5):

A version for Qt Designer inspired from @x squared. To use it, promote a QToolButton and designate a QFrame to it for collapsing contents.

[image: Preview]

CollapseButton.h:

```
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#pragma once

class CollapseButton : public QToolButton {
public:
  CollapseButton(QWidget *parent) : QToolButton(parent), content_(nullptr) {
    setCheckable(true);
    setStyleSheet("background:none");
    setIconSize(QSize(8, 8));
    setFont(QApplication::font());
    connect(this, &QToolButton::toggled, [=](bool checked) {
      setArrowType(checked ? Qt::ArrowType::DownArrow : Qt::ArrowType::RightArrow);
      content_ != nullptr && checked ? showContent() : hideContent();
    });
  }

  void setText(const QString &text) {
    QToolButton::setText(" " + text);
  }

  void setContent(QWidget *content) {
    assert(content != nullptr);
    content_ = content;
    auto animation_ = new QPropertyAnimation(content_, "maximumHeight"); // QObject with auto delete
    animation_->setStartValue(0);
    animation_->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutQuad);
    animation_->setDuration(300);
    animation_->setEndValue(content->geometry().height() + 10);
    animator_.addAnimation(animation_);
    if (!isChecked()) {
      content->setMaximumHeight(0);
    }
  }

  void hideContent() {
    animator_.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
    animator_.start();
  }

  void showContent() {
    animator_.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
    animator_.start();
  }

private:
  QWidget *content_;
  QParallelAnimationGroup animator_;
};
```

In mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  ui->setupUi(this);
  ui->toolButton->setContent(ui->contentFrame);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Contributing a version using PySide2 (official Qt5 bindings for python3)

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Expander(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title='', animationDuration=300):
        """
        References:
            # Adapted from PyQt4 version
            https://stackoverflow.com/a/37927256/386398
            # Adapted from c++ version
            https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119983/386398
        """
        super(Expander, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
        self.toggleAnimation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup()
        self.contentArea =  QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.headerLine =   QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.toggleButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.mainLayout =   QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        toggleButton = self.toggleButton
        toggleButton.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; }")
        toggleButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        toggleButton.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        toggleButton.setText(str(title))
        toggleButton.setCheckable(True)
        toggleButton.setChecked(False)

        headerLine = self.headerLine
        headerLine.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        headerLine.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        headerLine.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        self.contentArea.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { background-color: white; border: none; }")
        self.contentArea.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        # start out collapsed
        self.contentArea.setMaximumHeight(0)
        self.contentArea.setMinimumHeight(0)
        # let the entire widget grow and shrink with its content
        toggleAnimation = self.toggleAnimation
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.contentArea, b"maximumHeight"))
        # don't waste space
        mainLayout = self.mainLayout
        mainLayout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        row = 0
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.toggleButton, row, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.headerLine, row, 2, 1, 1)
        row += 1
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.contentArea, row, 0, 1, 3)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        def start_animation(checked):
            arrow_type = QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
            direction = QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward if checked else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
            toggleButton.setArrowType(arrow_type)
            self.toggleAnimation.setDirection(direction)
            self.toggleAnimation.start()

        self.toggleButton.clicked.connect(start_animation)

    def setContentLayout(self, contentLayout):
        # Not sure if this is equivalent to self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.setLayout(contentLayout)
        collapsedHeight = self.sizeHint().height() - self.contentArea.maximumHeight()
        contentHeight = contentLayout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount()-1):
            expandAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(i)
            expandAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
            expandAnimation.setStartValue(collapsedHeight)
            expandAnimation.setEndValue(collapsedHeight + contentHeight)
        contentAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount() - 1)
        contentAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
        contentAnimation.setStartValue(0)
        contentAnimation.setEndValue(contentHeight)
```

Answer (score 3):

I built **Python3/Qt5** styled example to test out a StyleSheet class I'm writing.
I also fixed an issue with size calculations that didn't consider size changes to the expander button.

I also changed the method to `setLayout()` to be consistent with Qt.

[image: Expander Closed]

[image: Expander Open]

```
import sys
import inspect
import textwrap
from collections import OrderedDict, UserString
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



class QStyleSheet(UserString):
    """
    Represent stylesheets as dictionary key value pairs.
    Update complex stylesheets easily modifying only the attributes you need
    Allow for attribute inheritance or defaulting of stylesheets.

    # TODO support [readOnly="true"] attribute-selectors
            QTextEdit, QListView  <-- you can have multiple classes.
            QCheckBox::indicator  <-- some psuedo classes have double colons
    """
    def __init__(self, cls=None, name=None, psuedo=None, **styles):
        """
        Arguments to the constructor allow you to default different properties of the CSS Class.
        Any argument defined here will be global to this StyleSheet and cannot be overidden later.

        :param cls: Default style prefix class to ``cls``
        :param name: Default object name to ``name`` (hashtag) is not needed.
        :param psuedo: Default psuedo class to ``psuedo``, example: ``:hover``
        """
        self.cls_scope = cls
        self.psuedo_scope = psuedo
        self.name_scope = name
        self._styles = OrderedDict() # we'll preserve the order of attributes given - python 3.6+
        if styles:
            self.setStylesDict(OrderedDict(styles))

    def _ident(self, cls=None, name=None, psuedo=None):

        # -- ensure value is of correct type ----------------------------------------
        if cls is not None and not inspect.isclass(cls):
            raise ValueError(f'cls must be None or a class object, got: {type(cls)}')

        if name is not None and not isinstance(name, str):
            raise ValueError(f'name must be None or a str, got: {type(name)}')

        if psuedo is not None and not isinstance(psuedo, str):
            raise ValueError(f'psuedo must be None or a str, got: {type(psuedo)}')

        # -- ensure not overiding defaults -------------------------------------------
        if cls is not None and self.cls_scope is not None:
            raise ValueError(f'cls was set in __init__, you cannot override it')

        if name is not None and self.name_scope is not None:
            raise ValueError(f'name was set in __init__, you cannot override it')

        if psuedo is not None and self.psuedo_scope is not None:
            raise ValueError(f'psuedo was set in __init__, you cannot override it')

        # -- apply defaults if set ---------------------------------------------------
        if cls is None and self.cls_scope is not None:
            cls = self.cls_scope

        if name is None and self.name_scope is not None:
            name = self.name_scope

        if psuedo is None and self.psuedo_scope is not None:
            psuedo = self.psuedo_scope

        # return a tuple that can be used as a dictionary key.
        ident = tuple([getattr(cls, '__name__', None), name or None, psuedo or None])
        return ident

    def _class_definition(self, ident):
        """Get the class definition string"""
        cls, name, psuedo = ident
        return '%s%s%s' % (cls or '', name or '', psuedo or '')

    def _fix_underscores(self, styles):
        return OrderedDict([(k.replace('_', '-'), v) for k,v in styles.items()])

    def setStylesStr(self, styles):
        """
        Parse styles from a string and set them on this object.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()
        self._update()

    def setStylesDict(self, styles, cls=None, name=None, psuedo=None):
        """
        Set styles using a dictionary instead of keyword arguments
        """
        styles = self._fix_underscores(styles)
        if not isinstance(styles, dict):
            raise ValueError(f'`styles` must be dict, got: {type(styles)}')
        if not styles:
            raise ValueError('`styles` cannot be empty')

        ident = self._ident(cls, name, psuedo)
        stored = self._styles.get(ident, OrderedDict())
        stored.update(styles)
        self._styles[ident] = stored

        self._update()

    def setStyles(self, cls=None, name=None, psuedo=None, **styles):
        """
        Set or update styles according to the CSS Class definition provided by (cls, name, psuedo) using keyword-arguments.

        Any css attribute with a hyphen ``-`` character should be changed to an underscore ``_`` when passed as a keyword argument.

        Example::

            Lets suppose we want to create the css class:

                QFrame#BorderTest { background-color: white; margin:4px; border:1px solid #a5a5a5; border-radius: 10px;}

            >>> stylesheet.setStyle(cls=QFrameBorderTest, background_color='white', margin='4px', border_radius='10px')

            >>> print(stylesheet)

            QFrame#BorderTest { background-color: white; margin:4px; border:1px solid #a5a5a5; border-radius: 10px;}
        """
        styles = OrderedDict(styles)
        self.setStylesDict(styles=styles, cls=cls, name=name, psuedo=psuedo)

    def getStyles(self, cls=None, name=None, psuedo=None):
        """
        Return the dictionary representations of styles for the CSS Class definition provided by (cls, name, psuedo)

        :returns: styles dict (keys with hyphens)
        """
        ident = self._ident(cls, name, psuedo)
        return self._styles.get(ident)

    def getClassIdents(self):
        """Get all class identifier tuples"""
        return list(self._styles.keys())

    def getClassDefinitions(self):
        """Get all css class definitions, but not the css attributes/body"""
        return [self._class_definition(ident) for ident in self.getClassIdents()]

    def validate(self):
        """
        Validate all the styles and attributes on this class
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def merge(self, stylesheet, overwrite=True):
        """
        Merge another QStyleSheet with this QStyleSheet.
        The QStyleSheet passed as an argument will be left un-modified.

        :param overwrite: if set to True the matching class definitions will be overwritten
                          with attributes and values from ``stylesheet``.
                          Otherwise, the css attributes will be updated from ``stylesheet``
        :type overwrite: QStyleSheet
        """
        for ident in stylesheet.getClassIdents():
            styles = stylesheet.getStyles(ident)
            cls, name, psuedo = ident
            self.setStylesDict(styles, cls=cls, name=name, psuedo=psuedo)

        self._update()

    def clear(self, cls=None, name=None, psuedo=None):
        """
        Clear styles matching the Class definition

        The style dictionary cleared will be returned

        None will be returned if nothing was cleared.
        """
        ident = self._ident(cls, name, psuedo)
        return self._styles.pop(ident, None)

    def _update(self):
        """Update the internal string representation"""
        stylesheet = []
        for ident, styles in self._styles.items():
            if not styles:
                continue
            css_cls = self._class_definition(ident)
            css_cls = css_cls + ' ' if css_cls else ''
            styles_str = '\n'.join([f'{k}: {v};' for k, v in styles.items()])

            styles_str = textwrap.indent(styles_str, ''.ljust(4))
            stylesheet.append('%s{\n%s\n}' % (css_cls, styles_str))

        self.data = '\n\n'.join(stylesheet)


class Expander(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title=None, animationDuration=200):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
        self.toggleAnimation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup()
        self.contentArea = QScrollArea()
        self.headerLine = QFrame()
        self.toggleButton = QToolButton()
        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()

        toggleButton = self.toggleButton
        self.toggleButtonQStyle = QStyleSheet(QToolButton, border='none')
        toggleButton.setStyleSheet(str(self.toggleButtonQStyle))
        toggleButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        toggleButton.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        toggleButton.setText(title or '')
        toggleButton.setCheckable(True)
        toggleButton.setChecked(False)
        toggleButton.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        headerLine = self.headerLine
        self.headerLineQStyle = QStyleSheet(QFrame)
        headerLine.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)  # see: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qframe.html#Shape-enum
        headerLine.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)   # see: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qframe.html#Shape-enum
        headerLine.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        self.contentAreaQStyle = QStyleSheet(QScrollArea, border='none')
        self.contentArea.setStyleSheet(str(self.contentAreaQStyle))
        self.contentArea.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        # start out collapsed
        self.contentArea.setMaximumHeight(0)
        self.contentArea.setMinimumHeight(0)
        # let the entire widget grow and shrink with its content
        toggleAnimation = self.toggleAnimation
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.contentArea, b"maximumHeight"))
        # don't waste space
        mainLayout = self.mainLayout
        mainLayout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        row = 0
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.toggleButton, row, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.headerLine, row, 2, 1, 1)
        row += 1
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.contentArea, row, 0, 1, 3)
        super().setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        def start_animation(checked):
            arrow_type = QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
            direction = QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward if checked else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
            toggleButton.setArrowType(arrow_type)
            self.toggleAnimation.setDirection(direction)
            self.toggleAnimation.start()

        self.toggleButton.clicked.connect(start_animation)

    def setHeaderFrameStyles(self, styles):
        self._setWidgetStyles(self.headerLine, self.headerLineQStyle, styles)

    def setToggleButtonStyles(self, styles):
        self._setWidgetStyles(self.toggleButton, self.toggleButtonQStyle, styles)

    def setContentAreaStyles(self, styles):
        self._setWidgetStyles(self.contentArea, self.contentAreaQStyle, styles)

    def _setWidgetStyles(self, widget, qstylesheet, var):
        if isinstance(var, QStyleSheet):
            qstylesheet.merge(var)
            widget.setStyleSheet(str(qstylesheet))
        elif isinstance(var, dict):
            qstylesheet.setStylesDict(var)
            widget.setStyleSheet(str(qstylesheet))
        elif isinstance(var, str):
            widget.setStyleSheet(var)
        else:
            raise ValueError('invalid argument type: {type(var)}')



    def setLayout(self, contentLayout):
        """
        Set the layout container that you would like to expand/collapse.

        This should be called after all styles are set.
        """
        # Not sure if this is equivalent to self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.setLayout(contentLayout)
        collapsedHeight = self.toggleButton.sizeHint().height()
        contentHeight = contentLayout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount()-1):
            spoilerAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(i)
            spoilerAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
            spoilerAnimation.setStartValue(collapsedHeight)
            spoilerAnimation.setEndValue(collapsedHeight + contentHeight)
        contentAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount() - 1)
        contentAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
        contentAnimation.setStartValue(0)
        contentAnimation.setEndValue(contentHeight)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    LIGHT_BLUE = '#148cc1'
    MED_BLUE = '#0c6a94'
    DARK_BLUE = '#0a3a6b'
    PALE_SALMON = '#fd756d'
    LIGHT_GREY = '#d2d5da'
    SLATE = '#525863'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.WINDOW_STYLE = QStyleSheet(QMainWindow, background_color=self.SLATE)
        self.WINDOW_STYLE = str(self.WINDOW_STYLE)

        self.LABEL_STYLE = QStyleSheet(QLabel, color=self.DARK_BLUE, font_weight=400, font_size='9pt')
        self.LABEL_STYLE = str(self.LABEL_STYLE)

        # -- QPushButton stylesheet ---------------------
        self.BUTTON_STYLE = s1 = QStyleSheet()

        s1.setStyles(cls=QPushButton, 
                    color='white', 
                    font_weight=400,
                    border_style='solid',
                    padding='4px',
                    background_color=self.LIGHT_BLUE)

        s1.setStyles(cls=QPushButton, psuedo=':pressed',
                    background_color=self.PALE_SALMON)

        s1.setStyles(cls=QPushButton, psuedo=':focus-pressed',
                    background_color=self.PALE_SALMON)

        s1.setStyles(cls=QPushButton, psuedo=':disabled',
                    background_color=self.LIGHT_GREY)

        s1.setStyles(cls=QPushButton, psuedo=':checked',
                    background_color=self.PALE_SALMON)

        s1.setStyles(cls=QPushButton, psuedo=':hover:!pressed:!checked',
                    background_color=self.MED_BLUE)
        self.BUTTON_STYLE = str(self.BUTTON_STYLE)

        self.BUTTON_GROUPBOX_STYLE = QStyleSheet(QGroupBox, border='none', font_weight='bold', color='white')
        self.BUTTON_GROUPBOX_STYLE = str(self.BUTTON_GROUPBOX_STYLE)

        self.TEXT_EDIT_STYLE = QStyleSheet(QTextEdit, color='white', border=f'1px solid {self.LIGHT_BLUE}', background_color=self.MED_BLUE)
        self.TEXT_EDIT_STYLE = str(self.TEXT_EDIT_STYLE)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        contents_vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        label_box = QHBoxLayout()
        for text in ('hello', 'goodbye', 'adios'):
            lbl = QLabel(text)
            lbl.setStyleSheet(self.LABEL_STYLE)
            lbl.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            label_box.addWidget(lbl)

        button_group = QButtonGroup()
        button_group.setExclusive(True)
        button_group.buttonClicked.connect(self._button_clicked)
        self.button_group = button_group 

        button_hbox = QHBoxLayout()


        for _id, text in enumerate(('small', 'medium', 'large')):
            btn = QPushButton(text)
            btn.setCheckable(True)
            btn.setStyleSheet(self.BUTTON_STYLE)
            button_group.addButton(btn)
            button_group.setId(btn, _id)
            button_hbox.addWidget(btn)

        button_group.buttons()[0].toggle()

        text_area = QTextEdit()
        text_area.setPlaceholderText('Type a greeting here')
        text_area.setStyleSheet(self.TEXT_EDIT_STYLE)

        contents_vbox.addLayout(label_box)
        contents_vbox.addLayout(button_hbox)
        contents_vbox.addWidget(text_area)

        collapsible = Expander(self, 'Expander')
        collapsible.setToggleButtonStyles({'padding': '4px', 'background-color': 'white'})
        collapsible.setContentAreaStyles({'background-color': 'white'})
        collapsible.setLayout(contents_vbox)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(collapsible)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Expander')
        self.setStyleSheet(self.WINDOW_STYLE)
        self.show()

    def _button_clicked(self, button):
        """
        For the toggle behavior of a QButtonGroup to work you must 
        connect the clicked signal!
        """
        print('button-active', self.button_group.id(button))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I applied is to use the MaximumSize property of the widget to limit the height while folded.

The biggest problem is to know the the unfolded height while folded to allow a correct animation step. This has not been solved and I currently make an animation with a fix height step (which I set to an appropriate value in relation to the expected height of the window).

```
if (toBeFolded)
{
    unfoldedMaxHeight = maximumHeight();
    previousUnfoldedHeight = height();
    setMaximumHeight(25);
}
else
{
    // animate maximumHeight from 25 up to where the height do not change
    // A hint of the final maximumHeight is the previousUnfoldedHeight.
    // After animation, set maximumHeight back to unfoldedMaxHeight.
}
```

Comment: No sure this fits your context, I ended up using `widget.setVisible(not widget.isVisible())` instead of messing with size calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The original question wanted to use the widget in Qt Designer, so here is a fork of @x squared's repo I made: https://github.com/seanngpack/qt-collapsible-section

It works with QT5, to make it work with Qt designer you just have to build and install the repo.

There's not much documentation on how to do this, so I may make a post later describing the process.