# How to convert this cpp widget into pyqt5?

Tags: plugins, pyqt5

I've tried to convert this into pyqt5 but I can't do it correctly. I want to convert the widget into pyqt5 this is reference [How to make an expandable/collapsable section widget in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476006/how-to-make-an-expandable-collapsable-section-widget-in-qt)

Complete code is here: https://github.com/Elypson/qt-collapsible-section

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "Section.h"
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Section* section = new Section("Section", 300, ui->centralWidget);
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(section);

    auto* anyLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    anyLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("Some Text in Section", section));
    anyLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Button in Section", section));

    section->setContentLayout(*anyLayout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Show whatever PyQt5 code you have so far.

Comment: The 94th request for free work today! Great...