# qt can't find "closable box" ui style

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface, pyside

I'm unable to find the type of menu behaving like the one you can see on image below :

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: This widget does not exist by default, but could create it, are you using pyside?

Comment: Ok. Yes I am using PySide

Comment: There is a similar question in [SO: How to make an expandable/collapsable section widget in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32476006/7478597) though it is asked and answered in C++. The general concept is to have QCheckbox which shows/hide another widget (e.g. a QFrame). The rest is (hopefully) done by the Qt layout manager. To make it more stylish, you may change the look of the QCheckBox.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll look into that :)