# QTreeWidget icon

Tags: qt, icons, qtreewidget

I'm developing an `Qt` application and I was displaying some data in `QTreeWidget` widget, but I needed it to adjust it to fit it's content so I changed the `QTreeWidget` to a custom widget from this post : [How to make an expandable/collapsable section widget in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476006/how-to-make-an-expandable-collapsable-section-widget-in-qt)

However I really don't like the arrow icon

[image]

And I would like to have the previous icon from `QTreeWidget`

[image]

Is that some standard default icon I could easily switch to? If so where do I found it?

Comment: try to add image via stylesheet `QTreeWidget::branch:open {
    image: url(branch-open.png);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Add a branch image to your qss file

```
QTreeWidget::branch:open { image: url(branch-open.png);}
```

see complete example [here](https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/styling-qt-qtreeview-with-css/)

Comment: Hi, as I said I am not using a `QTreeWidget`, I just want the icon.