# Qt: Map a clicked signal to another button

Tags: qt, click, signals-slots, qt-signals

I wanted to have a collapsible widget. I used this code: [How to make an expandable/collapsable section widget in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476006/how-to-make-an-expandable-collapsable-section-widget-in-qt).

I wanted the title of the `QToolButton` to be on the far left and the triangle icon to be on the right. I deleted the title, and moved the icon. Then I created a `QPushButton` and made it look like a `QLabel` and positioned it where I wanted the title to be. Now, I would like the title to be clickable - to have the same effect as clicking on the toggle icon would have. How do I connect these two signals?

Code for the `QToolButton`:

```
QObject::connect(toggleButton, &QToolButton::clicked, [this](const bool checked)
{
    toggleButton->setArrowType(checked ? Qt::ArrowType::DownArrow : Qt::ArrowType::UpArrow);
    toggleAnimation->setDirection(checked ? QAbstractAnimation::Forward : QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
    toggleAnimation->start();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write it like this:

```
QObject::connect(titleLabel, &QPushButten::clicked, toggleButton, &QToolButton::clicked);
```

Comment: This didn't have the desired effect - the animation filckered, but it didn't expand. But `QObject::connect(titleLabel, &QToolButton::clicked, toggleButton, &QToolButton::click);` worked as it should. So thanks!

Comment: Ah of course this works too. My answer requires you to connect the toggleButton’s `clicked()` signal to a slot, I assumed that this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```
QObject::connect(titleLabel, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]
{
    toggleButton->click();
});
```

Disclaimer: I have no idea if that is the correct way to do this.