# Collapsable Widget in QT

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I would like to have a collapsable Widget like seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476006/how-to-make-an-expandable-collapsable-section-widget-in-qt). The Problem with the accepted solution for me: I want to **dynamically change the content of the collapse-widget** (adding / removing widgets while it is collapsed or expanded). The provided solution **copies the content height on creation**, and is thus not responsible as I need.

I already experimented a lot with Layout-SizeConstraint and Widget-Sizehints, but did not manage to adjust the solution there to be responsive.

How can I create a collapsable widget that **allows for content size changes**?