# Create stacked vertical submenus that display/hide widgets whenever they are clicked

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5, widget

I want to create a widget in PyQt5 that works as a "stacked submenu": once the user clicks on a specific label/row, a bunch of related options/widgets appear below. These submenus can be stacked on top of each other, like in the desired example below (a screenshot from LibreOffice Impress):

#### What I want

[image]

My current attempt is below: I'm using a `QPushButton` responsible for showing/hiding a `QFrame` containing arbitrary widgets. The basic idea is here, but this is sort of a "manual" approach.

#### What I got so far

[image]

#### The code

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QLabel, QPushButton,
                             QVBoxLayout, QWidget)


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)

        # Layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Row, widgets are placed in a frame below
        self.row = QPushButton('Graphs')
        layout.addWidget(self.row)

        # Frame where widgets are placed
        self.frame = QFrame()
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        # Add a layout and some widgets to the frame
        self.frame.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.frame.layout().addWidget(QLabel('Data 1'))
        self.frame.layout().addWidget(QLabel('Data 2'))
        self.frame.layout().addWidget(QPushButton('New Graph...'))
        self.frame.setVisible(False)

        # Show/hide frame when row is clicked
        self.row.clicked.connect(self.toggle_frame)

    def toggle_frame(self) -> None:
        if self.frame.isVisible():
            self.frame.setVisible(False)
        else:
            self.frame.setVisible(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MyApp()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Maybe PyQt5 has a built-in way of creating such a submenu? I'm not sure what to even call such a design, so I'm having trouble looking for answers. I Tried messing with a `QTreeWidget` but I failed to find an option to show/hide all elements in the tree (and adding arbitrary widgets/layouts to a `QTreeWidget` seems a bit hacky). Or is my approach the way to go, just lacking a bit of styling/layout management?

Comment: Something like this? [How to create collapsible box in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617714)

Comment: @musicamante yes, exactly! Thanks a lot, I had no idea that this design was called "collapsible box". It worked perfectly for my needs :)