# I want to know the name of the widget that can display information such as an accordion, but in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, widget

I am trying to learn PyQt an the Qt designer has a widget un the inspector that is a dropbutton but when you display it it is not a list,it can contains another widgets you can interact with, and set, what is its name, can I find it in Pyqt.

Note: it is similar to an accordion in HTML

Accurate answers and resolve my doubts

[image]

Comment: [QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html) (and its inherited higher level QTreeWidget) is what is used in Designer. What you're showing in the animation may be something based on it (each top level item only has one child item, which shows a custom widget with its own layout). Alternatively, you can do something similar with a "collapsible box", as shown here: [How to create collapsible box in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52615115).

Comment: in musescore qml and custom designed widgets is used, as far as I know