# How to make a nestable expandable widget in Qt

Tags: python, pyside2

Similar to [How to make an expandable/collapsable section widget in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32476006/386398) I want expandable sections in my Qt app. So I've translated the example to PySide2(Qt5).
Everything looks fine until I nest expanders:

[image: nested expander fails]

As far as my current understanding goes it seems that the maximumHeight is only calculated once (when setContentLayout is called).

I guess I would need to update parents maximumHeight when expanding via the inner animation, but I have no Idea where to start.

Nested reproduction example

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Expander(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title='', animationDuration=300):
        """
        References:
            # Adapted from PyQt4 version
            https://stackoverflow.com/a/37927256/386398
            # Adapted from c++ version
            https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119983/386398
        """
        super(Expander, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
        self.toggleAnimation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup()
        self.contentArea =  QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.headerLine =   QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.toggleButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.mainLayout =   QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        toggleButton = self.toggleButton
        toggleButton.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; }")
        toggleButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        toggleButton.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        toggleButton.setText(str(title))
        toggleButton.setCheckable(True)
        toggleButton.setChecked(False)

        headerLine = self.headerLine
        headerLine.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        headerLine.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        headerLine.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        self.contentArea.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { background-color: white; border: none; }")
        self.contentArea.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        # start out collapsed
        self.contentArea.setMaximumHeight(0)
        self.contentArea.setMinimumHeight(0)
        # let the entire widget grow and shrink with its content
        toggleAnimation = self.toggleAnimation
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.contentArea, b"maximumHeight"))
        # don't waste space
        mainLayout = self.mainLayout
        mainLayout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        row = 0
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.toggleButton, row, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.headerLine, row, 2, 1, 1)
        row += 1
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.contentArea, row, 0, 1, 3)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        def start_animation(checked):
            arrow_type = QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
            direction = QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward if checked else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
            toggleButton.setArrowType(arrow_type)
            self.toggleAnimation.setDirection(direction)
            self.toggleAnimation.start()

        self.toggleButton.clicked.connect(start_animation)

    def setContentLayout(self, contentLayout):
        # Not sure if this is equivalent to self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.setLayout(contentLayout)
        collapsedHeight = self.sizeHint().height() - self.contentArea.maximumHeight()
        contentHeight = contentLayout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount()-1):
            expandAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(i)
            expandAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
            expandAnimation.setStartValue(collapsedHeight)
            expandAnimation.setEndValue(collapsedHeight + contentHeight)
        contentAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount() - 1)
        contentAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
        contentAnimation.setStartValue(0)
        contentAnimation.setEndValue(contentHeight)


from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication()
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
window.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(QLabel('above'))

inner = QVBoxLayout()
inner.addWidget(QLabel('innertop'))
inex = Expander(title='inner')
innest = QVBoxLayout()
innest.addWidget(QLabel('content'))
inex.setContentLayout(innest)
inner.addWidget(inex)
inner.addWidget(QLabel('innerbottom'))

ex = Expander(title='outer')
ex.setContentLayout(inner)

layout.addWidget(ex)
layout.addWidget(QLabel('below'))
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up consuming the containers resizeEvent to update the min/max constraints.

Here's the working example

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ScrollArea(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    resized = QtCore.Signal()
    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        self.resized.emit()
        return super(ScrollArea, self).resizeEvent(e)

class Expander(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title='', animationDuration=300):
        """
        References:
            # Adapted from PyQt4 version
            https://stackoverflow.com/a/37927256/386398
            # Adapted from c++ version
            https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119983/386398
        """
        super(Expander, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
        self.toggleAnimation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup()
        self.contentArea =  ScrollArea()
        self.headerLine =   QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.toggleButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.mainLayout =   QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        toggleButton = self.toggleButton
        toggleButton.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; }")
        toggleButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        toggleButton.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        toggleButton.setText(str(title))
        toggleButton.setCheckable(True)
        toggleButton.setChecked(False)

        headerLine = self.headerLine
        headerLine.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        headerLine.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        headerLine.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        self.contentArea.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { background-color: white; border: none; }")
        self.contentArea.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        # start out collapsed
        self.contentArea.setMaximumHeight(0)
        self.contentArea.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.contentArea.resized.connect(self.updateContentLayout)

        # let the entire widget grow and shrink with its content
        toggleAnimation = self.toggleAnimation
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight"))
        toggleAnimation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.contentArea, b"maximumHeight"))

        mainLayout = self.mainLayout
        mainLayout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        row = 0
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.toggleButton, row, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.headerLine, row, 2, 1, 1)
        row += 1
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.contentArea, row, 0, 1, 3)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        def start_animation(checked):
            arrow_type = QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
            direction = QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward if checked else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
            toggleButton.setArrowType(arrow_type)
            self.toggleAnimation.setDirection(direction)
            self.toggleAnimation.start()

        self.toggleButton.clicked.connect(start_animation)

    def updateContentLayout(self):
        if self.toggleButton.isChecked() and self.toggleAnimation.state() != self.toggleAnimation.Running:
          collapsedHeight = self.sizeHint().height() - self.contentArea.maximumHeight()
          contentHeight = self.contentArea.layout().sizeHint().height()
          self.setMinimumHeight(collapsedHeight + contentHeight)
          self.setMaximumHeight(collapsedHeight + contentHeight)
          self.contentArea.setMaximumHeight(contentHeight)
        self.updateGeometry()
        p = self.parent()
        if isinstance(p, ScrollArea):
          p.resized.emit()

    def setContentLayout(self, contentLayout):
        # Not sure if this is equivalent to self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.destroy()
        self.contentArea.setLayout(contentLayout)
        collapsedHeight = self.sizeHint().height() - self.contentArea.maximumHeight()
        contentHeight = contentLayout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount()-1):
            expandAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(i)
            expandAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
            expandAnimation.setStartValue(collapsedHeight)
            expandAnimation.setEndValue(collapsedHeight + contentHeight)
        contentAnimation = self.toggleAnimation.animationAt(self.toggleAnimation.animationCount() - 1)
        contentAnimation.setDuration(self.animationDuration)
        contentAnimation.setStartValue(0)
        contentAnimation.setEndValue(contentHeight)


from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication()
window = QWidget()
layout = QFormLayout()
window.setLayout(layout)
layout.addRow(QLabel('above'))

inner = QFormLayout()
inner.addRow(QLabel('innertop'))
inex = Expander(title='inner')
innest = QFormLayout()
innest.addRow(QLabel('content'))
inex.setContentLayout(innest)
inner.addRow(inex)
inner.addRow(QLabel('innerbottom'))

ex = Expander(title='outer')
ex.setContentLayout(inner)

layout.addRow(ex)
layout.addRow(QLabel('below'))
window.show()
app.exec_()
```