# Expandable "statusbar" in Qt (QtDesigner)?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Basically, what I want to implement is, a sort of an "expandable statusbar" (not sure if there is another name for it); in essence, in "collapsed state", it would be just a plain statusbar, able to show text strings/messages - except it has a "button" for expanding, here a "+":

[image: stat01.png]

When the expanding button is clicked, then the statusbar expands into a panel, covering about 1/3rd of the window (however, not "pushing" the preexesting widgets in the window, just covering them) - and the button changes into a "-":

[image: stat02.png]

Of course, then I'd want different widgets in the expanded state panel; likewise, if here I click on "-", I go back to the collapsed statusbar state.

I was wandering:

- Is there already an existing widget in Qt that would be especially applicable to implementing something like this?
- If not, is it possible to somehow implement this widget with existing QtWidgets, such that: at least the collapsed state is shown in QtDesigner UI, - and toggling between collapsed and expanded state is shown in QtDesigner Preview (that is, without a standalone application)?
- If previous is not possible - is it possible to code a custom widget (in a form of a .dll, maybe?) that, when imported in QtDesigner, would demonstrate toggling in QtDesigner preview?
- Ignoring QtDesigner, what would be the recommended setup to implement something like this purely in code (say, in PyQt5)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is already a post discussing this - it is here:

- [How to make an expandable/collapsable section widget in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476006/how-to-make-an-expandable-collapsable-section-widget-in-qt)