# Qt - TableView with categories

Tags: c++, qt

I am looking to replicate the look of the TableView presented in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGMlW.png) using Qt.  The one in the picture looks to be created with Windows Forms.  The main part I'm wondering about is how the different items have different categories kind of (with each section having a header).

Is it possible to do this in a Qt TableView, or do I need to use a TreeView?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476006/how-to-make-an-expandable-collapsable-section-widget-in-qt).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.